# how to hide navigation drawer indicator while using appcompat21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I am using the toolbar widget as the ActionBar following Cris Banes Guide.
In my use case, i needed to hide the navigation drawer in the activity while swiping to another fragment contained inside ViewPager. 
Previously, I was using the following properties while using the ActionBar Widget to hide the navigation Drawer. This seemed to work properly.
`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`

though now changing to AppCompat21 when using

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

This Doesn't seem to hide the navigation drawer in the actionBar.
Am I missing something in this regard any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

It will hide the navigation icon, for reference you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291205/646806)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to hide the navigation icon but i am not using a custom icon for setIcon. So how would i get the navigation drawer indicator back.

Comment: thanks got it working with toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `Toolbar` inside the `DrawerLayout`  --> `AppBarLayout`

then the class

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle-->setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)
```

function will make the nav drawer icon invisible.like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
//the below line of code will allow you to hide the nav drawer icon 
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);    
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a back arrow icon shown instead of the hamburger (3 lines) icon. :-(

Comment: ...oops. That was happening because I still had `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` . Remove those and it's now working nicely. 10 points! :-)

Answer (score 7):

your code should work only when you use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

and

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

you can try also:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

Comment: thanks toolbar.setNavi.. seems to hide it though for displaying it back ihad to use.   toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));

Comment: @harshitpthk I hate resorting to hacky solutions like that, but sometimes it can't be helped.

Comment: Just a note to internet voyagers who may come after... it's important that you use getSupportActionBar(), NOT getActionBar() 