# How to hide navigation drawer toggle button when search view expands

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I want my search view widget to fill the entire toolbar so in menu.xml I did this:

```
...
app:showAsAction="always"
```

This seem to hide all other items in the toolbar when search view expands, but not the drawer toggle button:

[image]

Is there anyway I can make the search view widget fill the entire toolbar and hide the toggle button too? 
Thanks

Comment: i think you should use this instead of remove drawer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524290/change-toolbar-color-style-on-searchview-click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by hiding the hamburger button. Set your toolbar navigation icon to null.

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

**EDIT**

To remove the navigation icon, add the following line in your `onCreate` method.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

To make the SearchView fill the action bar, set the width of the SearchView to max in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
SearchView searchView = 
(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

and

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

or you can try this:

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);

check [here][1] for more details


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291001/how-does-one-remove-default-toolbar-menu-items-and-replace-with-different-icons/28291205#28291205